# A person who supports some idea but hid it in public

Tags: word-choice

I was looking for a word which is perfect for a person who supports some idea but hid that idea in public for some reason.

**For example**

I believe in gender equality but if someone or any group talks against it then I opt to be quite and ignore any further debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "closet supporter" might be a good fit. It derives from the expression "[in the closet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_closet)."

> I am a closet gender equality supporter.

Originally this phrase was strongly associated with LGBT concerns as mentioned in the Wikipedia page. But in contemporary usage it has come to find more general usage. As an example, in Chicago you might hear someone describe themselves as a "closet [Cardinals](https://www.mlb.com/cardinals) fan," meaning they like the St. Louis Cardinals but are afraid to admit it in public.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would add though that if someone says "*I am a closet [x]*" then it isn't a complete secret from *everybody*. There is also a similar prefix "armchair [x]" which is used when someone is perhaps very vocal about something in their own home but doesn't actually do anything about it elsewhere. "Closet" better implies the secrecy, but if someone is glib about referring to themselves as a "closet [x]" then in a way they are also an "armchair [x]"!